# Issues while showing content in collection view inside table view in swift

Tags: ios, swift

i have used collection view inside the table view and populate data inside the collection view coming from backend. Now when i reload the data it does not shows me UI in a way i'm trying to show, i want my UI to look like this,
[image]

But when i run my app and open the VC my table view looks like that, 
[image]

Data is not coming in horizontal way and its duplicating the cell of collection view. This is my code for Collection view to populate data inside it.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return categoryArray[section].blogArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "familyCell", for: indexPath) as! FamilyCVC

    cell.categoryLbl.text = categoryArray[indexPath.section].blogArray[indexPath.row].articleTitle
    let imageUrl = categoryArray[indexPath.section].blogArray[indexPath.row].imageUrl!
    print(imageUrl)
    cell.categoryImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "person.jpeg"))
    cell.bgView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cell.bgView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cell.bgView.layer.shadowOpacity = 3
    cell.bgView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
    cell.bgView.layer.shadowRadius = 2
    cell.bgView.layer.shouldRasterize = true

    return cell
}
```

This is the code for table view holding collection view ,

```
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return categoryArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return categoryArray.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 35
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("KnowledgeHeaderTVC", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! KnowledgeHeaderTVC

    headerView.categoryNameLbl.text = categoryArray[section].catName
    headerView.articlesLbl.text = "\(categoryArray[section].blogArray.count)" + "articles"

    return headerView
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = knowledgeTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "KnowledgeCell", for: indexPath) as! KnowledgeDetailTVC

    //cell.categoryArray = categoryArray
    cell.categoryCollectionView.delegate = self
    cell.categoryCollectionView.dataSource = self
    cell.categoryCollectionView.reloadData()

    return cell
}
```

I want to show my data in UI like the first image in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You may need

1-

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return 1 // change this to 1
}
```

2-

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = knowledgeTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "KnowledgeCell", for: indexPath) as! KnowledgeDetailTVC

    cell.categoryCollectionView.tag = indexPath.section // add this
    cell.categoryCollectionView.delegate = self
    cell.categoryCollectionView.dataSource = self
    cell.categoryCollectionView.reloadData()

    return cell
}
```

3-

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return categoryArray[collectionView.tag].blogArray.count // use tag here 
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "familyCell", for: indexPath) as! FamilyCVC

    cell.categoryLbl.text = categoryArray[collectionView.tag].blogArray[indexPath.row].articleTitle
    let imageUrl = categoryArray[collectionView.tag].blogArray[indexPath.row].imageUrl!
    print(imageUrl)
    cell.categoryImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "person.jpeg"))
    cell.bgView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cell.bgView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cell.bgView.layer.shadowOpacity = 3
    cell.bgView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
    cell.bgView.layer.shadowRadius = 2
    cell.bgView.layer.shouldRasterize = true

    return cell
}
```

Comment: It is crashing on this delegate, 
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("KnowledgeHeaderTVC", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! KnowledgeHeaderTVC
        
        headerView.categoryNameLbl.text = categoryArray[section].catName
        headerView.articlesLbl.text = "\(categoryArray[section].blogArray.count)" + "articles"
        
        return headerView
    }. with index out of range error on this line headerView.categoryNameLbl.text = categoryArray[section].catName. @Sh_Khan

Comment: changed `numberOfRowsInSection `  ??

Comment: Yeah i placed the code as u have mention in answer but getting crash in  viewForHeaderInSection delegate. @Sh_Khan